# Android Mask ImageView with Circular Progress View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, porter-duff

I am trying to mask an imageview with a [CircularProgressView](https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View) using PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN here is the sample code for masking

```
 public static Bitmap getMaskedBitmap(Resources res,  int sourceResId,Bitmap mask) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        options.inMutable = true;
    }
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, sourceResId, options);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (source.isMutable()) {
        bitmap = source;
    } else {
        bitmap = source.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        source.recycle();
    }
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);

    mask.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}
```

source image = will be a transparent letter "C" from the drawables like this one [image]

and the mask image should be from the CircularProgressView.I want to fill the transparent letter "C" with solid white color base on points (ratio like 1/10) using the CircularProgressView masking the letter C. Is it possible?